# wso2esb - Add https to my api

Tags: api, rest, https, wso2, wso2-esb

I have this simple example of my rest api, and now I want to add https capabilities to this resource.

```
<api name="API_FEETIT_VERSION" context="/api_feetit_version">
  <resource methods="GET" protocol="https">
     <inSequence>
        <send>
           <endpoint>
              <address uri="http://myserver.net/version"/>
           </endpoint>
        </send>
     </inSequence>
  </resource>
```

To do this I just added attribute protocol="https" on resource, but now I cant access the service. Already try on port 8243 but still nothing.

Do I need to do anything else? Or even my endpoint service needs to use https too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , your backend service will need to be https as well as your endpoint address.

```
 <address uri="https://myserver.net/version"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't wso2 ebs provides any way to make https available without having to change endpoint's code?

Comment: I seems like it does , but does not show it on the ui. Try this :

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to the ESB Management console.
2. Under "Service Bus" section/tab , click the last option "Source View".
3. Search(ctrl-f) for you API , then its resource , and check if protocol="https". This is one of mine:

   <   resource methods="POST"
               protocol="https"
               inSequence="ackServiceSeq"
               outSequence="hcfRequest"/   >

Weird how the "invokation url" stays the same

Comment: but "ackServiceSeq" and "hcfRequest" are custom sequences, right?

And on "ackServiceSeq" I need to provide the endpoint reference, which should use https, right?

Comment: You should share more info on what you've done so far , I can't guess your configuration's .